# Trace transactions end to end over distributed applications systems

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

Is there a way to trace transactions end to end over distributed applications system using Spring AOP or AspectJ, without changing the existing codes? The web service interactions between applications may be RMI, SOAP or REST? I am looking for a general approach and just want to know if it possible using Spring AOP and AspectJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with AspectJ, but there is no easy "cooking recipe" or "template for dummies". You need a custom solution. In order to concretely answer your question I would have to see your code. Another guy from India lately asked me the same, maybe he works on the same project as you.

The general approach is to transfer state between client and server by injecting a unique parameter (something like a transaction ID) into the request and using it on the server. Both client and server should be aspect-enabled. This should be possible via RMI, SOAP and REST, provided you find a place where to inject an additional parameter. In RMI and SOAP this could be an existing general-purpose key-value dictionary for optional parameters, in REST it could be a header field or a request parameter.